# How to fit image height to a modal div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple problem, but unable to resolve it. I have searched the web and read tons of different things but did not find the case of a modal window nor works in my case.

I've done a REALLY light lightbox to open an image + some others elements
I want the image to fit the modal and adjust his width/height and keep proportions.

Maybe I'm a little bit lost with all my

```
height:100%
```

Here is the Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vrsap3hh/8/

An idea?

Thanks & Regards.

EDIT : Here are 2 screenshots
What I have : http://hpics.li/5c32814
What I want : http://hpics.li/0ba4e07

And the image could be any size, portrait or landscape.

Comment: your `#editor .main` has padding that doesn't allow it to fit the modal

Comment: It's fine. The problem is the h1 margin-bottom. I don't think your style is hitting it. If you add  `h1{     margin-bottom: 0 !important; }` it fits just fine.

Comment: Thanks, sorry maybe i'm not clear, I want the Image+components fit the modal window (#editor width: 70%; height: 90%;) and prevent scrollbar

Comment: Sorry @G. I misunderstood.

Comment: No problem, thank you for your answer, to be more precise, I want to have this http://hpics.li/0ba4e07

Comment: And the image could be any size, portrait or landscape. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#editor .main 
        {
            padding: 0; //changed this
            max-width: 1580px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

#editor .main > header h1 {
        font-size: 25px;
        line-height: 44px;
        margin: 0;
        /* font-weight: 700; */
        color: #333;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 0px; //changed this
 }
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/vrsap3hh/2/)

Comment: Thanks, sorry maybe i'm not clear, I want the Image+components fit the modal window and prevent scrollbar.

Comment: Like that : http://hpics.li/5c32814 to http://hpics.li/0ba4e07
Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1):

set your height and width to auto in both .editorContent and #editorOverlay and set your overflow to `hidden`  here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrsap3hh/4/) - jquery 2.13 doesn't run in snippets

```js
$('#editorOverlay, #editorClose').on('click', function(event) {
    $("#editor, #editorOverlay").fadeOut(500);
});

$( '.showEditor').on('click', function(event) {
    $("#editor, #editorOverlay").fadeIn(500);
});
```

```css
#editor{
 display:none;
 line-height: 18px;
}

#editorClose {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.editorTextright {
    float: right;
}

.editorContent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 15%;
    width: 70%;
    height: 90%;
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
}
#editorOverlay {
 display:none;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}


#editor .support-note span{
 color: #ac375d;
 font-size: 16px;
 display: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px 0;
}

#editor .main {
 padding: 30px 20px 0px 20px;
 max-width: 1580px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#editor .main > header {
 padding: 0 10px 30px;
}

#editor .main > header h1 {
 font-size: 25px;
 line-height: 44px;
 margin: 0;
 /* font-weight: 700; */
 color: #333;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}


#editor #content {
 /*width: 980px;*/
 /*width: 95%;*/
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}


#editor #photo{
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a href="javascript:;" class="showEditor">CONTENT</a></p>
<p><a href="javascript:;" class="showEditor">CONTENT</a></p>
<p><a href="javascript:;" class="showEditor">CONTENT</a></p>
<p><a href="javascript:;" class="showEditor">CONTENT</a></p>
<p><a href="javascript:;" class="showEditor">CONTENT</a></p>
<p><a href="javascript:;" class="showEditor">CONTENT</a></p>
```

**EDIT (2):**

or if the pic can be any size then try this out [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrsap3hh/15/) and [result](http://jsfiddle.net/vrsap3hh/15/embedded/result)

```js
$('#editorOverlay, #editorClose').on('click', function(event) {
    $("#editor, #editorOverlay").fadeOut(500);
});

$( '.showEditor').on('click', function(event) {
    $("#editor, #editorOverlay").fadeIn(500);
});
```

```css
#editor{
 display:none;
 line-height: 18px;
}

#editorClose {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.editorTextright {
    float: right;
}

.editorContent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 15%;
    width: 70%;
    height: 90vh;
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: hidden;
     border:1px solid #ccc;
}
#editorOverlay {
 display:none;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    height: 90vh;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
   
}


#editor .support-note span{
 color: #ac375d;
 font-size: 16px;
 display: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px 0;
}

#editor #main {
 padding: 30px 20px 0px 20px;
 max-width: 1580px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#editor #main > header {
 padding: 0 10px 30px;
}

#editor #main > header h1 {
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 10px;
 margin: 0;
 /* font-weight: 700; */
 color: #333;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}


#editor .content {
 /*width: 980px;*/
 /*width: 95%;*/
 width: 100%;
    max-height:90vh;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}


#editor #photo{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-height:55vh;
    height:auto;
}
.stickerbox{margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
.stickerbox img{width:100px; height:100px;}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>

<p><a href="javascript:;" class="showEditor">CONTENT</a></p>
<p><a href="javascript:;" class="showEditor">CONTENT</a></p>
<p><a href="javascript:;" class="showEditor">CONTENT</a></p>

<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>


<div id="editorOverlay"></div>

<div id="editor">
 <div class="editorContent">
 
  <a href="javascript:;" class="editorTextright" id="editorClose"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
 
  <div class="main">
  
   <header>
    <h1>MODAL</h1>
   </header>
   
   <div id="content">
    
    
                <img id="photo" src="http://dummyimage.com/1666x2500/000/fff"></img>
                
    <h2>Some text</h2>
    <div class="stickerbox">
                        <img class="sticker"  src="http://i.imgur.com/v93I3ZL.png" alt="" />
      <img class="sticker"  src="http://i.imgur.com/v93I3ZL.png" alt="" />
         <img class="sticker"  src="http://i.imgur.com/v93I3ZL.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    
    <a class="create">Button</a>
            
  </div>
  
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but that dont seems to solve my problem.
See this 2 pictures : 
What I have : http://hpics.li/5c32814
What I want : http://hpics.li/0ba4e07
Thanks

Comment: remove the embedded/result to see the fiddle. all i did was adjust the width and height  of the photo to 70  and add margin 0 auto

Comment: Thank you for spending time on my problem.
With your code I get this http://hpics.li/b2ff59e, I loose the scrollbar, cool, but I dont want the modal popup change his proper size (width 70% of screen and height 90%), just as my second screenshot.
Just in case : The image could be any size, portrait or landscape.
Most of lighbox plugins could do that for me but I need img fitted PLUS html and I'm stucked here.
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

would be great if you post the whole code! but no problem. I dont if im getting the question in a proper way but I think that wha you can do is use those property that I will list now.

max-height

### max-width

min-height
min-width

in that way you will control the max size that your pocture will have and your picture will fit perfectly with your light box.

Comment: Hi !
This is near the whole code, I tryed to play with max-height but my image dont care... Do you think that could help me to get result from this screenshot http://hpics.li/5c32814 to this http://hpics.li/0ba4e07 ?
Regards

Comment: try to separate editor and photo.
here is the code, let me know if that helped you

#editor {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

#photo{
    
    display: block;
    max-width: 40%;
    max-height: 60%;
}